# Where are "Fragment Layout Name" and "Navigation Type" options for a new Android activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I am following some tutorials of how to make my first `android` app and have come across creating new activities, looking at the tutorials image of what display box I should have, it is different to what I actually have. I have installed all the latest updates for `eclipse 4.4 (Luna)` as well as the latest `SDK` and `ADT` plugins This is their screenshot, followed by mine:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone have any idea as to how to get the missing options of `Fragment Layout Name`  and `Navigation Type`?
I have tried creating a fragment for myself and adding it to the `XML` file but that still returns all sorts of errors.[I am following the tutorials from this place.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: is your project already created ?? and ad new activity?

Comment: The project has already been created, and this is the screen for me creating a new activity.

Comment: its very simple just create java class and extend your activity or fragment class relatively and create XML file for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot of the tutorial, they are creating a new activity by extending from MainActivity. May be the MainActivity is a tabbed Activity and it has an option to specify a Fragment and a navigation type...?

You, on the other hand are trying to create the MainActivity for the first time, but you have an issue declaring the layout file for it (the XML file holding the layout), because it already exists in your project. Do not specify it here. You can do that in code after you create the MainActivity in its onCreate method, like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem a lot as well. I just figured out that the tutorial says one part wrong and that is "Select **Blank Activity** and click **Next**". You should actually select **Blank Activity with Fragment**. That will have the Fragment Layout Name box. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmwUv.png Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images.